# Box style problem in Auto Multiple Choice - AMC

Tags: tikz-pgf, auto-multiple-choice

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz,xcolor}
\usepackage[box,completemulti]{automultiplechoice}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\AMCtext{draft}{}

\begin{document}

%\AMCboxStyle{shape=oval,color=red}
\begin{question}{sum}$2+2={}$
\begin{choiceshoriz}[o]
\wrongchoice{1}
\correctchoice{4}
\wrongchoice{10}
\end{choiceshoriz}
\end{question}

\onecopy{1}{}

\end{document}
```

I added the line,

```
\AMCboxStyle{shape=oval,color=red}
```

**Undefined control sequence**

Is there any way to solve?

Comment: You can get `automultiplechoice` from [here](http://home.gna.org/auto-qcm/).

Comment: I haven't tried, but it seems to be `\AMCboxDimensions{shape=oval}` and `\AMCboxColor{red}` (there is not `\AMCboxStyle`).

Comment: Perfect working, @HenriMenke

Comment: `\AMCboxStyle` is defined in the development version of AMC (will be available in AMC 1.3.0)

Comment: Could you or @HenriMenke write an answer to close this question?